# Netatalk 100x slower than scp with USB disk

Tags: server, samba, file-sharing, scp

I have netatalk install on a headless Ubuntu box on my lan. I have a usb drive mounted on /mnt/ext. When attempting to copy a ~700 MB file from the box using netatalk (afp) OR samba, my estimated time is ~3.5 hours. When using scp to copy the same files I complete the transfer in 5 minutes.

Anyone have a clue what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. The drive is a seagate POS.

explained here http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1005886